# How to use relative paths in require.config?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I'd like to distribute a piece of code as an AMD module. The module depends on jQuery in a noConflict mode with two jQuery plugins.

I'd like the user to be able to use the module by simply requiring a single module file (module will be hosted on our servers), and let the dependencies be handled for them. However, for the dependencies to be loaded properly, I have to invoke `require.config()` and it seems to have the module paths relative to the web page, not to the invoking script. I could use the `paths` configuration to make all the paths absolute. That would solve the dependency problem, but would also make testing anywhere outside our production server a nightmare.

To be more specific, the module file looks roughly like this:

```
define (['./jquery-wrapper'], function ($) {
    ...
    return module;
});
```

And the `jquery-wrapper.js` file in the same directory looks like this:

```
require.config ({
    paths: {
        'jquery-original': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min',
        // ^ naturally, this one has to be absolute
    },  
    shim: {
        'jquery-original': {
            exports: '$',
        },
        '../plugin/js/jquery.nouislider.min': {
            // ^ this path is relative to the web page, not to the module
            deps: ['jquery-original'],
        },
        '../plugin/js/jquery.ie.cors': {
            // ^ this path is relative to the web page, not to the module
            deps: ['jquery-original'],
        },
    },  
});         

define (['jquery-original', './jquery.nouislider.min', './jquery.ie.cors'], function ($, slider, cors) {
    // ^ these paths are relative to the module
    console.log ('types: ' + typeof slider + typeof $.noUiSlider + typeof cors);
    return $.noConflict (true);
});
```

Is there any way I can use paths relative to the module everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use separate configs to get this to work:

#### file structure

The `other/module` path simulates the other server in this example.

```
¦   a.js
¦   b.js
¦   c.js
¦   test.html
¦
+---other
    +---module
            main.js
            module-file-1.js
```

#### other/module/main.js

Has a dependency, using a relative module name.

```
define(["./module-file-1"], function (mf1) {
    console.log("load main", "deps", mf1);
    return "main";
});
```

#### a.js

Has a dependency, using a relative module name.

```
define(["./b"], function(b) {
    console.log("load a", "deps", b);
    return "a";
});
```

#### b.js and c.js

Uninteresting.

```
define(function () {
    console.log("load b");
    return "b";
});
```

#### other/module/module-file-1.js

Uninteresting.

```
define(function () {
    console.log("load module-file-1");
    return "module-file-1";
});
```

#### test.html

Set up two require contexts, use each to load their own modules, and then wait for both sets of modules to load:

```
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.8/comments/require.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var localRequire = require({
    context: "local"
});

var moduleRequire = require({
    context: "module",
    baseUrl: "http://localhost/other/module/"
});

function deferredRequire(require, deps) {
    return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
        require(deps, function() {
            dfd.resolve.apply(dfd, arguments);
        });
    }).promise();
}

$.when(deferredRequire(moduleRequire, ["main"]), deferredRequire(localRequire, ["a", "b", "c"])).then(function(deps1, deps2) {
    // deps1 isn't an array as there's only one dependency
    var main = deps1;
    var a = deps2[0];
    var b = deps2[1];
    var c = deps2[2];
    console.log("Finished", main, a, b, c);
});

</script>
```

## Console

```
load b
load a deps b
load c
load module-file-1
load main deps module-file-1
Finished main a b c
```